# Sonata admin bundle template

Tags: symfony, twig, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I recently installed Symfony & Sonata admin bundle, works fine.
Is it possible to change/custom the admin interface (template)? Where can I download these templates? Any tutorial how to do that?

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to change any template.
To do that, you need to:

- Install EasyExtendBundle
- Run the command $php app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate SonataAdminBundle -d src
- Register the generated bundle in AppKernel.php (the name will be ApplicationSonataAdminBundle)
- Copy the template you need to extend from the vendor directory and place it under the same hierarchy in your new bundle.
- Change your new template and add any block you want

PS: you can do the same thing with the CSS or JS files

Answer (score 3):

You can write your new templates, based or not on the sonata templates and after instruct the sonata admin to display your templates when a page is requested. In the Admin class you have to override the 'getTemplate' method, like this:

```
public function getTemplate($name)
{
    switch ($name) {
        case 'edit':
            return 'YourBundle:YourFolder:yourEdit.html.twig';
            break;
        case 'list':
            return 'YourBundle:YourFolder:yourList.html.twig';
            break;
        default:
            return parent::getTemplate($name);
            break;
    }
}
```

The example overrides the templates for 'edit' and 'list' actions. For the other actions it will get the sonata semplates.

Comment: Alternatively you can use the setter injection method for this example: http://blog.webdevilopers.net/override-list-view-twig-template-in-sonataadminbundle/

Answer (score 1):

You can simply override any template from the bundle. Check the doc [here](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/templates.html)

By default all the templates are configured in config.yml:

```
sonata_admin:
    templates:
        layout:  SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig
        ajax:    SonataAdminBundle::ajax_layout.html.twig
        list:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list.html.twig
        show:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show.html.twig
        edit:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:edit.html.twig
        history: SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:history.html.twig
        preview: SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:preview.html.twig
        delete:  SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:delete.html.twig
        batch:   SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list__batch.html.twig
        acl:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:acl.html.twig
        action:  SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:action.html.twig
        select:  SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list__select.html.twig
        dashboard:           SonataAdminBundle:Core:dashboard.html.twig
        search:              SonataAdminBundle:Core:search.html.twig
        batch_confirmation:  SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:batch_confirmation.html.twig
        inner_list_row:      SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_inner_row.html.twig
        base_list_field:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
        list_block:          SonataAdminBundle:Block:block_admin_list.html.twig
        user_block:          SonataAdminBundle:Core:user_block.html.twig
        pager_links:         SonataAdminBundle:Pager:links.html.twig
        pager_results:       SonataAdminBundle:Pager:results.html.twig
        history_revision_timestamp:  SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:history_revision_timestamp.html.twig
        short_object_description:    SonataAdminBundle:Helper:short-object-description.html.twig
        search_result_block: SonataAdminBundle:Block:block_search_result.html.twig
```